# If / if else logic in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

```
var h = game.ship.hull.hullIntegrity(); //returns int from 0-100
var hstr = h.toString()+"%";
gcp.hullIntegrity.text = hstr;
gcp.hullHealth.text = game.ship.hull.health;
//colorize data
console.log(h);
if (h === 100) {
    gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("#05AA0D",0);
} else if (75 <= h < 100) {
    console.log("yellow: ", h + " >= 75.");
    gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("#FFEC0D",0);
} else if (25 <= h < 75) {
    console.log("red:", h + " < 75.");
    gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("red",0);
} else if (h < 25) {
    console.log("grey");
    gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("grey",0);
}
```

I am trying to colorize the display of a canvas text object based on its value. For some reason, the previous code has the following behavior:

- When h = 100, it displays green. This is correct.
- When h < 100, it displays yellow. This is correct.
- When h < 75, it SHOULD display red. It displays yellow.

Console.log shows:

```
    70
    yellow:  70 >= 75.
```

But 70 is obviously less than 75, so why isn't the console displaying "red"?

Why?

Comment: you have to update your if statements and use some && for example: 
(75 <= h && h < 100)

Comment: Yes, using && returns the correct code. But when I put the code through jshint.com without the &&, it didn't flag the statements as incorrect. That seems very strange to me.

Comment: everything after 75 <= h got ignored u cant do 2 comparisons without saying that you really want to do 2 of them since 75 is smaller than h each time it will be yellow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
var h = game.ship.hull.hullIntegrity(); //returns int from 0-100
var hstr = h.toString()+"%";
gcp.hullIntegrity.text = hstr;
gcp.hullHealth.text = game.ship.hull.health;
//colorize data
console.log(h);
if (h === 100) {
   gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("#05AA0D",0);
} else if (h >= 75 && h < 100) {
   console.log("yellow: ", h + " >= 75.");
   gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("#FFEC0D",0);
} else if (h >= 75 && h < 100) {
   console.log("red:", h + " < 75.");
   gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("red",0);
} else if (h < 25) {
   console.log("grey");
   gcp.hullIntegrity.addColor("grey",0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use if like this

```
(h >= 75 && h < 100)
(h >= 25 && h < 75)
```

Comment: The second parts of both of those expressions are redundant - those cases are already handled by the previous conditional block